# how to get jsf clientid of a component in datatable?

Tags: jsf, datatable, components, clientid

i am trying to get the client id of a component in a datatable. the problem is that jsf puts row index before the component id automatically, i.e.

```
   <a id="mappedidentifier_table:1:mappedidentifier_Update" href="#">Update</a>
```

for a link in the second row (index=1).

i am using the following methods to get the clientId

```
   public static String findClientId(String id) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot view = context.getViewRoot();
        if (view == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");
        }
        UIComponent component = findComponent(view, id);
        if (component == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no component has id='" + id + "'");
        }
        return component.getClientId(context);
    }

    private static UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent component, String id) {
        if (id.equals(component.getId())) {
            return component;
        }

        Iterator<UIComponent> kids = component.getFacetsAndChildren();
        while (kids.hasNext()) {
            UIComponent kid = kids.next();
            UIComponent found = findComponent(kid, id);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

however this returns

`mappedidentifier_table:mappedidentifier_Update`,

instead of

`mappedidentifier_table:1:mappedidentifier_Update`,

therefore it does not match any element cause the row index in id is missing.

i've read http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/jsf-using-component-ids-in-data-table.html

however i intend to have a simpler implementation, rather than TLD function or facelets like the author did.

does anyone have any thoughts ?

thanks,

dzh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however this returns `mappedidentifier_table:mappedidentifier_Update` instead of `mappedidentifier_table:1:mappedidentifier_Update`

This will happen if you resolve the `clientId` outside the context of a row. The row context is set up at each stage of the lifecycle by the `UIData` control.

It might also happen if you're using immediate evaluation instead of deferred evaluation in your EL expressions - `${}` instead of `#{}`.

*As an aside, and as noted in the article, that lookup algorithm will only work if the component identifier is unique to the view; the spec says it need only be unique to the `NamingContainer`; this need not be a problem if you are careful about using unique component IDs on your page.*